# Method returning Arraylist empty

Tags: java, arraylist, empty-list

I currently need a copy of a list returned in a method so I use it in a for-each.
Class Employee extends User. I want a List returned only with the employees, which is an instance of User, but I think it's not working.

```
public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
        ArrayList<Employee> copy = new ArrayList<>();
        for(User user : ec.getUsersList().getUserList()){
            if(user instanceof Employee){
                copy.add((Employee) user);
            }
        }
        return copy;
    }
```

I want to use it here, and the for seems not to be running the list..

```
for (Employee a : c.getEmployeeList()) {
            if (!dispEmployee.contains(a)) {
                notSelectedEmployee.addElement(a.toString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you think it is not working?

Comment: Either you are iterating an empty list, or none of its elements are of that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a big fan of Java 8, lambdas, and a more functional style.  I might write it like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Filter {

    public static List<Employee> getEmployeeList(List<User> users) {
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        if (users != null) {
            employees = users.stream()
                    .filter(u -> u instanceof Employee)
                    .map(u -> (Employee) u)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return employees;
    }
}
```

My JUnit test passed; I think it's good.  User and Employee are simple guesses at what you were after.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FilterTest {

    @Test
    public void testFilter() {
        // setup
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(new User("foo", "bar"));
        users.add(new Employee("baz", "bat", "supervisor"));
        users.add(new User("x", "y"));
        users.add(new Employee("alpha", "omega", "developer"));
        List<Employee> expected = new ArrayList<>();
        expected.add((Employee) users.get(1));
        expected.add((Employee) users.get(3));
        // exercise
        List<Employee> actual = Filter.getEmployeeList(users);
        // assert
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Just noticed a minor problem on the way employees were being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK. Check the content of `ec.getUsersList().getUserList()`, does this list has any element?
Also you can rewrite you method in Java 8 style. It looks much simplier and shorter

```
public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
    //check for nulls ec, ec.getUsersList and so on
    return ec.getUsersList().getUserList().stream()
        .filter(user -> user instanceof Employee)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

Comment: The list works. I'm rewriting the code, that looks better :)